# Cron tab not reloading on linux - what am I doing wrong?

Tags: linux, cron

At the top of my `sudo crontab -e` result it shows this:

```
# DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE - edit the master and reinstall.
# (Dox-Web-1_CRONTAB installed on Fri Jul 30 17:51:25 2010)
# (Cron version V5.0 -- $Id: crontab.c,v 1.12 2004/01/23 18:56:42 vixie Exp $)
# DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE FROM CRONTAB
# EDIT ORIGINAL FILE /scripts/Dox-Web-1_CRONTAB
```

I edited the file specified here, then I tried `/etc/init.d/cron reload` `/etc/init.d/cron restart` but when I sudo edit the crontab it doesn't show up.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

After you edit `/scripts/Dox-Web-1_CRONTAB`, you need to run

```
$ crontab /scripts/Dox-Web-1_CRONTAB
```

which loads it into the user crontab file. You can verify it's been loaded by

```
$ crontab -l
```

It is ok to edit it with

```
$ crontab -e
```

The warning is saying that you should not edit the crontab files that are stored in `/var/spool/cron/crontabs/`, which is where `crontab filename` and `crontab -e` write to.

Also, you do not need to restart or reload the cron daemon. The `crontab` command tells the cron daemon that the crontab file has been updated.